# How to merge CSVs horizontally + avoid using commas to split pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have about 1000+ CSVs that need to be merged horizontally. This is my code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

dirname = r'path'
os.listdir(dirname)



extension = 'csv'

all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

dflist = []
for file in all_filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(dirname+file, header=None, sep='\n')
    print(df)
    df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
    dflist.append(df)

result = pd.concat(dflist, axis=1)
file_name = r'newfilenamepath'
result.to_csv(file_name)
```

The problem is that the data includes items like "Bob's Company, Ltd" which will end up getting separated into two columns: "Bob's Company" and "Ltd" because I am splitting based on commas. Splitting with anything other than a comma leads to some really funky formatting. The CSVs involved do not have the same headers, # of columns, or # of rows. I simply want to put them one next to each other.

If it's relevant, I managed to write code to merge them vertically and there may be a simple edit that I need to make to merge them horizontally instead:

```
Dir = r'path'
files = os.listdir(Dir)
file_name = 'mergedcsvfilename'
with open(file_name + '.csv','w') as wf:
    for file in files:
        if '.DS_Store' not in file:
            with open(Dir + file) as rf:
                for line in rf:
                    if line.strip(): # if line is not empty
                        if not line.endswith("\n"):
                            line+="\n"
                        wf.write(line)
```

Comment: If commas are used as data field delimiters _and_ appear inside the data fields, I do not see a way of deciding whether a comma is a delimiter or not. Are the string values included in quotes? Can you show an example of your input data?

Comment: Use the `quotechar='"'` option for `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Please add a few lines in text format from your CSV file to your question. Normally commas are automatically ignored if they are inside quotes.

Comment: do you need to match lines in the files or are you looking for a simple horizontal merge, i.e. line1 with line1, 2 with 2 etc...

Answer (score 0):

to merge them horizontally without using pandas

```
Dir = r'path'
files = [ open(f.name,"r") for f in os.scandir(Dir) if f.is_file() and '.DS_Store' not in f.name ]
with open(file_name + '.csv','w') as wf:
    while True:
        r = ','.join([f.readline().rstrip('\n') for f in files])
        if not r.rstrip(','): break
        wf.write(r)

map(lambda f: f.close(), files)
```

this assumes that all files have the same number of lines and same number of columns